# Start-up problems VirtualBox 4.3.20 after windows update 11 dec 2014,

Tags: windows, virtualbox

Yesterday Windows did some updates, and now VirualBox won't start any VM's.

Gives 'vboxdrv' driver not found errors and after fixing that it still wont start up any VM's.

Giving this error

```
The virtual machine 'ubuntu' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Resultaatcode:E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component:Machine
Interface:IMachine {480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048}
```

Hoping one of you came across a solution to problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that update (KB3004394) messed 2 of my windows 7 hosts for Virtual Box 4.3.20.
After removing the update, everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after windows update. I simply reinstalled VirtualBox and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused for update KB3004394 of the Windows 7.
Uninstall this update resouve the problem!